# Where can I find Pokémon Adventures Volumes 1-3 Chuang Yi Version not Viz Media

Tags: pokemon, singapore

I can't seem to find them anywhere I really want the uncensored Singapore version of Pokémon Adventures.

Answer (score 3):

[Chuang Yi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuang_Yi) has [closed down](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2014-02-21/chuang-yi-publishing-in-liquidation) for [some time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW5Au.png) and has ceased operations for even longer. IMO, if you want to acquire this version, it is through second hand sources like ebay.